# org.eclipse.swt.*; The import org.eclipse cannot be resolved

Tags: eclipse, import, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to write a small program that requires the import statement `import org.eclipse.swt.*;`. (I'm practicing with [THIS](http://eclipsepluginsite.com/swt.html) tutorial).

However, Eclipse won't compile the program and is giving me the error "`The import org.eclipse cannot be resolved`"

Google hasn't been such a a great friend at finding the answer this time.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is because you haven't added the SWT library to your buildpath. Follow the steps of the tutorial:

> 1. Download SWT library. For 3.1.2 version of eclipse, SWT library is available at
>      http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.1.2-200601181600/index.php
>      Look for the section titled SWT Binary and Source.
> 2. From main menu tool bar, select "File" followed by "Import". Doing so will bring up the "Import wizard" dialog.
> 3. Now select "Existing Projects into Workspace" and click on "Next" button.
> 4. Click on "Select archive file" followed by "Browse" button. Now locate the SWT archive that you downloaded in step 1.
> 5. Click the Finish button to finish importing the SWT project into your workspace.
> 6. Create new java project from File > New Java Project.
> 7. Right-click on the project and select the Properties command to open the Properties dialog.
> 8. Select the Java Build Path followed by Projects tab and click the Add button.
> 9. Select the org.eclipse.swt project and click OK to finish adding the SWT libraries to your project's classpath

Comment: I took all these steps. I no longer get the error, but the program doesn't run because: `Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform`. Do you know if there's any way around this?

Comment: @Imray: Maybe you have downloaded the wrong SWT version. 32bit where you should have 64bit. There are several question about this error on stackoverflow also...

Answer (score 8):

Create a Maven project and add `org.eclipse.swt` dependency in `pom.xml`:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.swt.org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64.4.3.swt/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.swt.org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64.4.3.swt</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64</artifactId>
    <version>4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find the 64bit version of the SWT library by changing the download url to this:
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.3-201306052000/swt-4.3-win32-win32-x86_64.zip

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, was using wrong settings in the target file.
If you are working with a target-definition make sure to use the right platform/architecture settings, see

[image]