# Imported Github projects - Many errors: The import org.eclipse cannot be resolved

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to import these two projects from GitHub into Eclipse:

[Project1](https://github.com/NikolasHerbst/BUNGEE/tree/master)
[Project2](https://github.com/joakimkistowski/LIMBO)

I did this before on a Linux machine with Eclipse Kepler. Apart from having to install the AWS SDK, this worked smoothly.

But now I'm trying to import the project into Eclipse Oxygen on Windows. I'm getting import errors "The import org.eclipse cannot be resolved" left right and center:

Some examples of what can't be imported:

```
import org.eclipse.emf.edit.command.SetCommand;
import org.eclipse.jface.action.IAction;
import org.eclipse.ui.IEditorPart;
import org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EClass;
```

I managed to resolve some of the errors by finding and downloading separate .jar files from the internet and adding them into a User Library. I resolved one error by following the below: 
[org.eclipse.swt.*; The import org.eclipse cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16442294/org-eclipse-swt-the-import-org-eclipse-cannot-be-resolved)

But I'm getting the feeling that having to resolve these issues one by one can't be right, especially since it worked on Linux without having to do this.

Am I maybe missing one major plugin, component or SDK that I need to install into Eclipse?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to fix the issue by using a different version of Eclipse:

["Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers"](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-rcp-and-rap-developers/oxygen2)